# Injecting iptables rule after libvirt network is created with terraform 0.11

Tags: terraform, iptables, libvirt

I have the following scenario: I'm using terraform (version 0.11) for creating multiple VMs with libvirt. VMs are attached to a NAT virtual network. As part of the VMs creation, some commands are executed on each VM by means of ssh. This works perfectly fine if VMs are created on the same machine where terraform runs.

Now, I want to be able to run terraform in my desktop and get the VMs created in another machine with more resources. I did this changing qemu's uri to point to the remote server. The VM creation works fine but when terraform tries to ssh into the VM from my machine, it fails because by default libvirt doesn't expose VMs to external access.

Therefore, I created an additional resource to run a command in the remote machine adding a rule to the iptables after the virtual network is created and before the VMs are accessed. See the code below as a reference. Please notice it is edited.

```
resource "libvirt_network" "network" {
  name   = "${var.stack_name}-network"
  mode   = "${var.network_mode}"  <-- this is NAT
  domain = "${var.dns_domain}"    

  dns = {
    enabled = true
  }

  addresses = ["${var.network_cidr}"]  <- 10.17.0.0/22
}

resource "null_resource" "iptables" {
  depends_on = ["libvirt_network.network"]

  connection {
    host     = <remote server>
    password = "******"
    user     = <ssh user>
    type     = "ssh"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d ${var.network_cidr} -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT",
    ]
  }
}

resource "libvirt_domain" "vm" {

  depends_on = ["null_resource.iptables"]
  count = "${vars.vms}" 
   ... 
}

resource "null_resource" "config" {
  depends_on = ["libvirt_domain.vm"]

  connection {
    host = "${element(libvirt_domain.vm.*.network_interface.0.addresses.0, count.index)}"
    ...
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {   <-- this is the remote exec on vm    

  }
}
```

This kind of works because the rule is added, BUT I need the new rule to be the first on the FORWARD chain. However, What I've seeing is that the rule is consistently added *after* the rules added by libvirt, as shown below:

```
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.17.0.0/22         ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     all  --  10.17.0.0/22         0.0.0.0/0           
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
5    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
6    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.17.0.0/22         tcp dpt:22
```

What I don't understand is why the iptables rule is created after the rules injected by libvirt if the iptables command is executed after the network is created and before the ssh to the Vms is executed (I have checked this in the terraform output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the answer to why your script is not working, but I can show you another way to achieve the same goal. Libvirt has a concept of "hooks" which are admin defined scripts to be run at certain key points in libvirt:

https://libvirt.org/hooks.html

There's an illustration of using hooks for port forwarding here:

https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking#Forwarding_Incoming_Connections